# How do I get the maturity date of an OIS with the Bloomberg Excel add-in?

Tags: bloomberg

I have an Excel sheet where I want USD OIS rates for tenors between 1 week and 1 year, as well as the maturity date of the swap as of 13/09/2018. Below picture shows what I currently have.

Column C has the same structure but includes the "PX_LAST" field instead of D1 (Maturity). When I enter the shown formula I get the error "#N/A N/A".

On the terminal, I have tried looking at the FLDS for the swap, which does include "MATURITY" as a field. When I use the @BDP formula instead, without specifying a historical date, it returns the maturity date for the given swap as of today. However, I need data from 13/09/2018.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You should use BQL, rather than the old BDH, and you should ask F1 F1 which field(s) to get. Or, run FLDS and search.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72972811

Comment: Also, =use "Cmdty" rather than "Curncy" for futures - although it works too,.